I ran into a problem regarding the textures and shading on some parts of my model
The images probably do a better way of explaining it than I will here but I will try my best. When I open my models on my laptop, some parts of my model's texture are just pure red. The crowsnest, the mast, the yard, the crates, even the main ship itself is all red. But it's weird because some elements such as the outline of the crates, the bottom half of the mast, and somehow all of the cannons all have their regular textures.
And it isn't because I'm in the wrong render view, I'm currently in Viewport Shading; which should display the textures and colors but not the lighting. So I'm kind of confused here. If anybody can help with this, that'd be great! If there's any extra info needed here, I'm more than happy to oblige. I do believe this is only affecting Blender on my LAPTOP and not on my PC since it was fine before then.



Are you sure they're not using a material tied to an image textures somewhere ? Usually pink means a texture is missing, because the link is broken and Blender can't find it anymore

Can confirm they are not using a material tied to image textures. As you can see on the shader editor below, I'm simply using some noise and voronoi textures along with a color ramp for some of the coloring. This is to create a wood like effect as I tried using an image texture but ran into another problem, namely, being dumb.
Edit: Would also like to add that, again, opening this model works completely fine on my PC, but since I'm running a bit short on time, I usually bring my laptop to run on the go. But opening it on laptop for some reason breaks it.

Then likely a hardware problem, are you sure the laptop adhere to the minimum hardware requirements ? Have you updated the graphics car drivers ?

It's most likely that. I had a look at my laptop specs and yeah, they do fit the minimum requirements and is pretty capable running Blender; it's more likely the specs are just that: MINIMUM. The textures did seem to hold a lot of rendering power on them so it's most probably my laptop couldn't handle it. Regardless, thank you for the reply! I'll look more into it if I can. Just needed to know maybe I hit a random setting that causes this.
